# Databricks API Executing sql command an waiting

Tags: asp.net-core, databricks

I am in need of creating an API to work with Databricks, one of which is to execute SQL commands on it. To execute an SQL query I have to send a request to execute it, then wait some time before calling another api that fetches for me the result of the SQL query. However I do not know how and what should I do between the two api calls, like I can't just put a delay. What do you think I should do and I need it to be efficient to handle some requests (no we're not talking about millions of requests, just good enough). This is all in ASP.Net Core, the APIs used:

- api/1.2/commands/execute
- api/1.2/commands/status

Answer (score 0):

Really, these APIs are for execution of notebooks commands on the Spark clusters. If you really want only to execute SQL commands, then you need to look onto [SQL Statement Execution API](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/statements.html) - it will be much easier to work with it than with the Commands API.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try and reply to you when I can, thank you so much!